# Nervana Neon AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sizeI'

Tags: python, deep-learning, nervana-neon

I'm a trying to do fprop with Nervana Neon, however, when I go to run model fprop I get the following error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sizeI'

I am following their example for fprop very close. I've trained the model using their `ImageLoader` and now I want to utilize the results in a system. I've tried using `model.get_outputs(ArrayIterator(myData))` but still issues. Any thoughts?

```
xdev = np.zeros((3 * 224 * 224, batch_size), dtype=np.float32)
xbuf = np.zeros((3 * 224 * 224, batch_size), dtype=np.float32)
img = to_neon(new_img) # function to flatten image to (3 * 224 * 224, ) 
xbuf[:,0] = img[:, 0]
model = model.load_params("/path/to/params.p")
out = model.fprop(xdev)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-fc650f5dcbc4> in <module>()
----> 1 out = model.fprop(xdev)

/root/neon/neon/models/model.pyc in fprop(self, x, inference)
    213             Tensor: the output of the final layer in the model
    214         """
--> 215         return self.layers.fprop(x, inference)
    216 
    217     def bprop(self, delta):

/root/neon/neon/layers/container.pyc in fprop(self, inputs, inference, beta)
    248                 x = l.fprop(x, inference, beta=beta)
    249             else:
--> 250                 x = l.fprop(x, inference)
    251 
    252         if inference:

/root/neon/neon/layers/layer.pyc in fprop(self, inputs, inference, beta)
    787         self.inputs = inputs
    788         self.be.fprop_conv(self.nglayer, inputs, self.W, self.outputs, beta=beta,
--> 789                            bsum=self.batch_sum)
    790         return self.outputs
    791 

/root/neon/neon/backends/nervanagpu.pyc in fprop_conv(self, layer, I, F, O, X, bias, bsum, alpha, beta, relu, brelu, slope, repeat)
   1936         repeat: used in benchmarking
   1937         """
-> 1938         assert layer.sizeI == I.size
   1939         assert layer.sizeF == F.size
   1940         assert layer.sizeO == O.size

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sizeI'
```

Comment: `None.size` - yup, doesn't have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working backwards on your stacktrace...

The problem comes from an attempt to dereference the `sizeI` attribute of a `layer` object when `layer` is `None`:

`-> 1938         assert layer.sizeI == I.size`

I'd call that a bug in the neon library (`backends/nervanagpu.py`)- it should have above that 1938 line something like:

```
    assert isinstance(layer, TheExpectedLayerClass)
```

A similar check could have been added even earlier, in `layers/layer.py`, before line 788:

```
    assert isinstance(self.nglayer, TheExpectedLayerClass)
```

But often hitting such bugs in 3rd party libs are simply indications that the library is not used in the way it was intended to. The bugs simply *obscure* the real cause by not making the proper checks earlier, where maybe it's clear what's missing.

So check the docs/tutorials, maybe you're missing some init/setup step, some additional argument somewhere, etc. Or, if you're more familiar with neon, keep going backwards on the stacktrace until you find what's missing.

Comment: I'm marking that as correct because I believe it is a bug. I haven't been able to replicate functionality described in the Neon docs but I did get things working by using an `ArrayIterator` and passing it to `mode.get_outputs()`